# In python3 tkinter, the wigdet frame doesn't show in interface

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, frame

I use the same format of frame but it doesn't show in the interface, hope someone could tell me the solution, thanks.

```
class Interface(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.master.title("measurement")
        self.grid()
        # fix the size and parameters of widget
        self.master.geometry("700x400+100+50")
        self.master.Frame1 = Frame(self,relief=GROOVE,bg='white')
        self.master.Frame1.grid(column=1,row=9)
        self.can =Canvas(self, bg="ivory", width =200, height =150)
        self.master.canvas = Canvas(self.master, width=150, height=120, background='snow')
        ligne1=self.master.canvas.create_line(75, 0, 75, 120)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Tk()
    window.resizable(False, False)

    Interface(window).mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out why you have 2 `Canvas`'s, but the problem is that you aren't placing them on their respective parents. I cut out a lot of the code that seemed unnecessary and restructured your code to make it more logical:

```
class Interface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        super().__init__(self.parent)
        self.Frame1 = Frame(self, relief=GROOVE)
        self.Frame1.grid()

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.Frame1, bg="ivory", width=200, height=150)
        self.canvas.grid()

        self.canvas.create_line(75, 0, 75, 120)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()

    # Tk configurations are not relevant to
    # the Interface and should be done out here
    root.title('Measurement')
    root.geometry('700x400+100+50')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    Interface(root).pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, I can't see the frame that I want.

Comment: @Anne-sophie could you describe what you want to see on the window? Your question is very vague.

Comment: I want to see a frame whose color is white and I want to see the line that canvas.create_line(75, 0, 75, 120) create.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The frame and the line are there. Frames only expand as big as they need to be unless you specify otherwise. The frame is around the canvas, it's just the same size as the canvas. To see that it's there, change `self.Frame1 = Frame(self, relief=GROOVE)` to `self.Frame1 = Frame(self, relief=GROOVE, bg='red')` and change `self.Frame.grid()` to `self.Frame1.grid(ipadx=10, ipady=10)`

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now

Answer (score 0):

i think I don't really understand your problem, you don't see your frame because you don't have any widget in it, that's all

```
import tkinter as tk

class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.master.title("measurement")
        self.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # fix the size and parameters of widget
        self.master.geometry("700x400+100+50")

        self.master.Frame1 = tk.Frame(self,relief='groove',bg='white')
        self.master.Frame1.grid(column=1,row=9)

        labelExemple =tk.Label(self.master.Frame1, text="Exemple")
        labelExemple.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.can = tk.Canvas(self, bg="ivory", width =200, height =150)
        self.master.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width=150, height=120, background='snow')
        self.ligne1=self.master.canvas.create_line(75, 0, 75, 120)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.resizable(False, False)    
    Interface(window).mainloop()
```

PS : use `import tkinter as tk` instead of `from tkinter import *`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I set bg='white' I still can't see the frame and when I use your programme,I just see the word example, without the color and the line

Comment: what's the advantages to use import tkinter as tk? I don't really understand

Comment: When you use `from tkinter import *`, you can sometimes cause 2 different things to get imported that use the same name. This is a big problem because the program might not use the one you want. But for very simple programs, you are probably fine using `from tkinter import *`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with those few lines of code, almost all having to do with the way you're using grid:

1. you aren't using the `sticky` option, so widgets won't expand to fill the space they are given
2. you aren't setting the `weight` for any rows or columns, so tkinter doesn't know how to allocate unused space
3. you aren't using `grid` or `pack` to put the canvases inside of frames, so the frames stay their default size of 1x1

The biggest problem is that you're trying to solve all of those problems at once. Layout problems are usually pretty simple to solve as long as you're only trying to solve one problem at a time.

Start by removing all of the widgets from Interface. Then, give that frame a distinctive background color and then try to make it fill the window (assuming that's ultimately what you want it to do). Also, remove the `root.resizable(False, False)`. It's rarely something a user would want (they like to be able to control their windows), plus it makes your job of debugging layout problems harder.

Once you get your instance of `Interface` to appear, add a single widget and make sure it appears too. Then add the next, and the next, adding one widget at a time and observing how it behaves.